# Firebase orderByChild query not returning ordered results

Tags: firebase

I am trying to use the Firebase `orderByChild()` function per the [documentation example](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html) but the queries are not coming back filtered or sorted.

Here is the sample data structure:

```
"notifications": { 
  "001": { 
    "member_id":      "abc123",
    "created_at":     1424357680681,
    "new":            true,
    "first_name":     "Jon",
    "last_name":      "Snow",
    "message":        "likes your photo"
  },
  "002": { 
    "member_id":      "abc456",
    "created_at":     1424357680681,
    "new":            true,
    "first_name":     "Clark",
    "last_name":      "Kent",
    "message":        "likes your comment"
  }
}
```

When a user logs in, I want to query the notifications hash for only the notifications with a `member_id` that matches the current user's id.

I have tried both versions with and without the "child_added".

Option A:

```
  ref.orderByChild("member_id").equalTo(memberId);
```

Option B:

```
  ref.orderByChild("member_id").equalTo(memberId)
    .on("child_added", function(data) { 
       console.log("new child id = " + data.key());
    });
```

When I query the notifications hash, the query returns an array of all of the notifications. They are neither limited to the `member_id` of the current user, nor sorted by `member_id`. (I can delete the member_id key entirely and the notification will still be returned).

I can always filter the returned array by `member_id` in-app, but I would really like to get the query working per the documentation.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem! 
I was under the impression that you could add the query modifiers in place.

I was doing:

```
  ref.orderByChild("member_id").equalTo(memberId);
  var sync = $firebase(ref);
```

It should actually be:

```
  var sync = $firebase(ref.orderByChild("member_id").equalTo(memberId));
```

Comment: Great that you found the solution Lena. Be sure to accept your self-answer once the system allows it. Sorry that I couldn't be more helpful. It would really help for your next question if you ensure that it contains a minimal, **complete**, verifiable example. I typically write those up in a jsfiddle or something like that, but most important is that it reproduces your actual problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your `memberId` variable is a number, while you're storing the corresponding value as a string.

If you store numbers as a string, this query won't give any results:

```
ref.orderByChild("member_id").equalTo(456)
```

But this one will:

```
ref.orderByChild("member_id").equalTo('456')
```

The easiest fix in your snippet of code is coercing the memberId to a string like this:

```
ref.orderByChild("member_id").equalTo(''+memberId)
```

See this fiddle for a working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/695rf0vy/

Comment: Thanks for answering. The member_id's are definitely strings because they are alphanumeric. Sorry, I oversimplified for the example.

Comment: In that case, please set up a reproduction of the problem. Feel free to modify the fiddle I posted into something that reproduces your problem. In general, posting an MCVE increases the chances that we can help you quickly (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).